# How to cancel class decorators in constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-descriptors, class-decorator

Lets take the following example of class decorators (origin http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1309289&seqNum=4):

```
class GenericDescriptor:

    def __init__(self, getter, setter):
        self.getter = getter
        self.setter = setter

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.getter(instance)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        return self.setter(instance, value)


def valid_string(attr_name, empty_allowed=True, regex=None,
                 acceptable=None):
    def decorator(cls):
        name = "__" + attr_name

        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, name)

        def setter(self, value):
            assert isinstance(value, str), (attr_name +
                                            " must be a string")
            if not empty_allowed and not value:
                raise ValueError("{0} may not be empty".format(
                    attr_name))
            if ((acceptable is not None and value not in acceptable) or
                    (regex is not None and not regex.match(value))):
                raise ValueError("{attr_name} cannot be set to "
                                 "{value}".format(**locals()))
            setattr(self, name, value)

        setattr(cls, attr_name, GenericDescriptor(getter, setter))
        return cls

    return decorator


@valid_string("name", empty_allowed=False)
class StockItem:
    name = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('second_call'):
            pass
            # proceed normally without calling @valid_string
        self.name = kwargs.get('name', None)
        self.price = kwargs.get('price', None)
        self.quantity = kwargs.get('quantity', None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()

    # valid value for name
    cameras1 = StockItem(name="Camera", price=45.99, quatity=2)
    # invalid value for name according to @valid_string but I need this to be also valid if 'second_call'
    cameras2 = StockItem(name=67, price=45.99, quatity=2, second_call=True)
```

The `StockItem` class constructor is invoked twice and on the second turn I want the @valid_string decorator to be somehow canceled (I don't want name attribute's value to be altered anymore).

Comment: Hell, Andreea, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*. Can you also clarify what exactly is the issue you are encountering? How do you know `__init__` is called twice?

Comment: No, you *shouldn't provide the whole code*, you should provide a [mcve]. If we cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing, it is hard to know how to help.

Comment: Ok guys, here is an example that works: https://jmp.sh/ADC2GvG (let me know if you cannot access the link)

Comment: Andreea, *please provide the [mcve] in the question itself*. Check out [ask], questions are required to be self-contained. Just copy and paste that code and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53342665/edit) into your question.

Comment: I've gone ahead and done the edit for you. But anyway, decorators cannot really be "canceled", they have already run by the time your class definition is finished executing (well, they are run immediately after). But you can subvert them, I suppose, but that would be easier if you can modify the decorator code somehow, or to do run-time modifications to the class (the latter option seems more brittle, but it may be easier or your only option if you can't touch the decorator code)

Comment: So, in other words, `# proceed normally without calling @valid_string` it is *too late*, `valid_string` has already been called. But you could do something like `if second_call: # modify self.__dict__ directly to add instance attributes`

Comment: Thank you... Ok, I understand it is too late. I was thinking, isn't it a way to cancel the decorator/decorators of the class just before calling it?:
        # valid value for name
        cameras1 = StockItem(name="Camera", price=45.99, quatity=2)

        StockItem.remove_decorators # but how?

        # invalid value for name according to @valid_string but I need this to be also valid if 'second_call'
        cameras2 = StockItem(name=67, price=45.99, quatity=2, second_call=True)